# ionic: ion-item in ion-list triggers page reload (ui.router)

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

i am using ionic (the original one, not meterionic) within meteorjs.

when i am using ion-item with a href the page is reloading, what i dont want to.

i tried to use  and is normally changing the state without reloading.

How can i change the behavior of ion-item to change only the state without reloading the whole single-page-application?

`<ion-list>
        <ion-item href="/home">Home (Page Reload)</ion-item>
        <ion-item><a href="/home">Home (no Page Reload)</a></ion-item>
    </ion-list>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, that one was obvious. it has to look like that:

`<ion-item ui-sref="app.home">Home</ion-item>`

Answer (score 0):

try to put a hash before the slash `href="#/home"` or just use ui-sref `ui-sref="home"`